# Formula for assigning a value to all working days between 2 dates

Tags: reporting, date, matrix

I am logging Sickness in salesforce and have a start and end date. For reporting purposes i need to be able to assign a 1 to each of the working days between these 2 dates.

Then when i report i can do a sum/count of the number of days that sit in each month where people are sick.

Thus, if I want to show a user as having a holiday on the following days: 29th Jan 30th Jan 31st Jan 1st Feb 2nd Feb and so on - they would have a start and end date recorded against the sickness record, and when i put it in a matrix report it would show sick days on each in that range.

Currently, this works fine if the sickness is all in one month - e.g. 4th Jan - 11th Jan

However when i go over the month end e.g. 29th Jan - 9th Feb i can only report on either the start or end date not split out the working days that fall into each month.

Comment: What edition are you using? You need to use the `BusinessHours` object and standard class together to do this sort of calculation. As long as you can use `Apex`...

Comment: I have never used Apex but found a solution using Process Builder.

I have created a seperate object and 2 process's that create 1 seperate object (days) based on the sickness start date

Then the second process keeps recurring this process until the Date of the (days) matches the sickness end date

Prob more elegent solutions using Apex but this works nicely for now... Now to just encorporate it to exclude the weekends :) Think i know how to do this though using a weekday formula

Comment: don't forget holidays!  Adrian's suggestion is most robust as you can configure your holiday calendars for many countries into the far future

Answer (score 0):

Unless you doing anything particularly clever to deduce "working days" between your two dates, in a formula you can simply mathematically compare dates as

```
End_Date__c - Start_Date__c
```

Which would give you the number of days between say Feb 9th and Jan 29th as 11.

Comment: Hi Simon,

Maybe i'm not explaining myself well. 

I from a reporting point of view i want to show the user as having a holiday on the following days:

29th Jan
30th Jan
31st Jan
1st Feb
2nd Feb

and so on - so when i put it in a matrix report it would allow me to show holidays on each day

A start and end date wouldnt give me that at it would just show 7 days against either the 29th Jan or 9th Feb

Hope that makes sense

Matt

Comment: ah right, so the matrix report is to resemble a calendar-like view? I'm afraid reporting is well outside my knowledgeable zone, esp. matrix reports. I'll drop this answer off soon (once I reckon on you having read this!) and hope someone else can help out.